# How to select a column or block of text in gedit 3.28.1?

Tags: 18.04, gedit

Is it possible to select a column or block of text in Gedit 3.28.1?

The following image is with Kate 17.12.3 but shows what I want:

[image: Column or block selection]

Comment: Supposedly the MultiEdit plugin (package `gedit-plugin-multi-edit`) adds column editing functionality

Comment: I posted it as a comment because I hadn't actually installed/tested it - why don't you go ahead and add your own answer, since you have done so

Comment: UltraEdit is amazing. Still think about try to use it under Linux wine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This answer is based on [steeldriver's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126156/how-to-select-a-column-or-block-of-text-in-gedit-3-28-1#comment1863801_1126156) to look into `gedit-plugin-multi-edit`.

I found [a blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/jessevdk/2009/11/15/new-gedit-plugin-multi-edit) which links to [a video](https://people.gnome.org/~jessevdk/multiedit.ogv) demonstrating column selection mode. Even though the links are from 2009, the plugin works in gedit 3.28.1 which is found in Bionic Beaver.

- Run `sudo apt install gedit-plugin-multi-edit`.
- Open *gedit > Preferences > Plugins* and enable *Multi Edit*.
- Then, when the need arises to perform edits involving columns, activate *Multi Edit Mode* from *Tools*. The mode will be reflected near the top right corner of the window.
- Left-click immediately to the left of the letter at the top left of the intended column and select down to include the lowest letter at the bottom right of the intended column.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- The selected area will change to cover just the column. Make the desired changes. They will be reflected onscreen.
- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>.
- Quit *Multi Edit Mode*.

Here's a brief animation derived from the video link cited above.

Animation illustrating column selection and editing:

[image: Animated gif showing column selection in gedit]

Comment: While the right click menu doesn't show a Copy option (after Enter in Multi-Edit mode), you can still Ctrl-C for copying the column (and paste into Excel/LibreOffice Calc).  I wouldn't have expected that Multi-Edit plugin could be use for this.

Comment: Can also use `Ctrl+Shift+C` to toggle Multi-Edit mode. Select multiline lines then `Enter` to convert to a column selection. `Ctrl+E` Toggle edit point at cursor position. [gedit-multi-edit](https://github.com/jessevdk/gedit-multi-edit/blob/master/README)

Comment: a very painful experience indeed. I suggest use VSCode it has multiline selection. just use alt-left click and drag