# GEdit multi-line edit on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gedit, plugins

The [multi-line edit mode](https://blogs.gnome.org/jessevdk/2009/11/15/new-gedit-plugin-multi-edit/) in GEdit is not working on Ubuntu 18.04. It can be activated with the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but presently it has no consequence. The basic sanity check shows the plug-in to be installed:

```
$ apt search gedit-plugin-multi-edit
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gedit-plugin-multi-edit/bionic,now 3.28.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Multi Edit plugin for gedit
```

What could be wrong here? Is there any other way to activate this plug-in?

Comment: @N0rbert this question deals with another aspect of the plugin and so may not be a dupe.

Comment: @DKBose I see you great answer here, so it is not a dupe, upvoted :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multi-line editing does work in gedit in Ubuntu 18.04.

This answer is based on [an answer I posted earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126156/how-to-select-a-column-or-block-of-text-in-gedit-3-28-1) about column mode editing in *gedit* and is with Ubuntu 18.04.

---

- `sudo apt install gedit-plugin-multi-edit` installs the necessary plugin.
- Open gedit > Preferences > Plugins and enable *Multi Edit*.
- Then, when the need arises to use *Multi Edit*, activate it from Tools. The mode will be reflected near the top right corner of the window.

[image: Activate Multi Edit via Tools]

- If you use the Adwaita GTK3 theme and hover the mouse pointer over the words *Multi Edit Mode*, you'll get an explanatory pop-up. (I couldn't get this popup to appear with Ambiance or Radiance GTK3 themes.)

[image: Explanatory popup]

- In the following image, I want to convert three instances of "true" to "false". I click at the end of the first instance of "true" as shown in the image and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. A brief message "Added edit point …" appears in the same row as *Multi Edit Mode*.

I click similarly for the other two instances of "true" pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> each time.

[image: marking multiple edit points]

- Once I'm done, simply press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the last instance of "true". The other two instances will be simultaneously removed.
- I then type "false" and it appears in all the three spots.

[image]

Turn off *Multi Edit Mode* from *Tools* once you're done.

---

In 19.04, the informative popup appears with Yaru as well. Ambiance still doesn't show it.