# How do I get rid of invalid characters in a plain-text file when using Gedit?

Tags: gedit, encoding

**Problem**

Gedit says that one of my files using UTF-8 encoding has invalid characters, and may get corrupted if I continue to use it.

**Details**

The file in questions is my Someday/Maybe List. I usually add to it links to sources I'd like to read, such as blog posts. I suspect that the link of one of the sources I added contained invalid characters, causing my issue.

I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72172/how-do-i-scan-for-invalid-characters-on-gedit) that I need to run isutf8, then use xxd or hexdump to scan a file for invalid characters. Running isutf8 is pointless because if [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/isutf8) is correct, all it does is tell you whether a file has invalid characters or not. I've read some manpages on xxd, and other sources on hexdump, but I don't understand any of it.

**What I've tried**

Not much. I fear I might break the file or something if I edit it, so I left it untouched. Besides, my research skills are poor, so I couldn't find a solution to this myself.

Comment: Did you also enter data in that text file with different tools, e.g. a different editor? I would never expect it possible to insert invalid characters while pasting directly in Gedit itself.

Comment: No, I didn't try that, but I will now.

Comment: I was suggesting: wrong characters could be introduced by different tools, so avoid that. But then, you say you never edited the file with a different tool. In that scenario, I find if strange wrong characters crept in.

Comment: Strange indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could in principle not happen if you exclusively use Gedit to edit the file. Characters in that case would be automatically converted to the character code of the current text file.

If for one reason incorrectly encoded characters would be introduced, then one way to find out where they are would be to use

```
grep -axv '.*' file.txt
```

(credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465612/how-to-detect-invalid-utf8-unicode-binary-in-a-text-file)). That command will only show lines containing invalid characters. To facilitate identification of the line, you can add the `-n` option to display the line number.

Then open the file in Gedit, continuing past the warning message that is given. You then can edit out the wrong characters. Save and close, then reopen the file. If no warning is issued anymore, all wrong characters have been removed.

Comment: This did it! Thanks!

It seems that I was right in that the links caused the issue. All of the lines containing wrong characters were of links. Perhaps a different encoding may prevent this from happening in the future.

By the way, do you know of any way to edit multiple lines at the same time? I tried installing multi-line edit for Gedit from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141714/gedit-multi-line-edit-on-ubuntu-18-04), as well as from other sources, but terminal says it couldn't locate the package. @vanadium

Comment: I find it really unexpected that copying a link in gedit would introduce invalid characters, but here you are. Could you perhaps share such a link? I would like to test this. No, I am not familiar with the multiline editing.

Comment: I just realized what may have caused the issue: Tagspaces. I use Tagspaces as a file manager, and I sometimes open .txt files using the built-in plain-text editor. I may have opened the files that ended up being corrupted with that editor. However, I find it strange that only those files were corrupted, but not my other files. Perhaps adding links plus using both text editors caused the problem. I'm uninstalling Tagspaces, so we'll see. @vanadium

Comment: Here's one of the corrupted lines: `Read: [Implementing Zettelkasten in Roam: A practical guide | RoamBrain.com](https://www.roambrain.com/implementing-zettelkasten-in-roam/)`

I'll continue my search on any way to install the multi-line edit mode plugin or anything like it. I have over 50 corrupted lines, so if I can avoid spending hours to fix the file, then nice.

Comment: Wonder what the anchor text was that originally was the source of the url and corrupted line. Maybe that contained the odd encoding and characters  [Could be NOT using "punycode" ].  Even if you find some odd character maybe you will need to link to its web location, & not try to paste it in to these comments.

Answer (score 0):

With luck [If such a file is only going to be used to be read in gedit or a similar text viewer all you will get is one or more unrecognised characters that will not display meaningfully]

If you only have one very recent change causing the problem its all very simple.

Make multiple backups of your current file AND the auto backup that gedit will have probably created for you.  There are many ways of copying and backing up files many can be automated but the easiest method right now is to note that Linux will let you have a file of the same name if it is in another directory folder or device.
So maybe create sub folders perhaps name them usenow1 backup1 & backup2 and copy the file in to each of those folders.

Note gedit allows auto backup preferences > editor > [x] Create backup file before saving.

If that was on you will already have a backup file saved automatically it will be the same name and location but will end with a swan-dash ~ character. If you have such a file make multiple copies of that at the same time.

You can now work with one of the copies confident that you will not destroy anything not already destroyed, and that you have backups. The file ending swandash is provably ok if you have closed down after first being warned. Rename that maybe to whatever the filename was with a v02 added before the .txt and the ~ at the end deleted. Open that with gedit and you should have a copy of the uncorupted file.

Now if you work with some command line tool or probably you  would prefer a GUI one try meld or something and you can compare the corrupt file and the one you have and sort out what you want to keep and what you want to delete.

You may be interested in checking your file with iconv see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch11.en.html#_checking_file_to_be_utf_8_with_iconv

Note also if you use save as gedit may offer other encoding options, and one may be appropriate to your newly added information.

Comment: Hey @John99, thanks for commenting.

Your suggestions are a bit laborious, but some of your ideas in combination with vanadium's solved my issue. Thanks a ton to both!

Comment: Good to here that. I was concerned you may lose data if you did not make multiple copies.